# How to return a value from one class to another in C# (ASP.NET 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a class with code (simplified):

```
namespace CustomerData
{
    public class InsertCustomer
    {
    public string name { get; set; }
        public string customerID { get; set; }

    public string Add()
    {
        //Insert into a database

        //Condition to check if the insert was successfull
        if (successful)
        {
            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            //If the insert was not successfull
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Now I want to pass this value to my web service (ASP.NET 2.0) in the same solution as the class above (simplified code):

```
namespace CustomerData
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] 

    [WebMethod]
        public string deleteCustomer(string customerID)
        {
            return customerID;
        }
```

And essentially I then want to have an AJAX GET function that gets this ID and execute a function with this variable but if I can get the value to my WebMethod I think I'll be good from there.

Any suggestions on how to do what topic describes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered calling your web method from your InsertCustomer class?

```
    CustomWebService srv  = new CustomWebService;
    srv.deleteCustomer(returnedCustomerID);
```